# GIScience/openrouteservice routing config the shortes instead of the fastest route

Tags: openstreetmap, openmap

I'm using GIScience/openrouteservice and would like to get the shortest route instead of the fastest. **Would it be correct to replace all fastest with shortest in the config below?**

```
"profile-car": {
            "profiles": "driving-car",
            "parameters": {
              "encoder_flags_size": 8,
              "encoder_options": "turn_costs=true|block_fords=false|use_acceleration=true",
              "maximum_distance": 100000,
              "elevation": true,
              "maximum_snapping_radius": 350,
              "preparation": {
                "min_network_size": 200,
                "min_one_way_network_size": 200,
                "methods": {
                  "ch": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "threads": 1,
                    "weightings": "fastest"
                  },
                  "lm": {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "threads": 1,
                    "weightings": "fastest,shortest",
                    "landmarks": 16
                  },
                  "core": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "threads": 1,
                    "weightings": "fastest,shortest",
                    "landmarks": 64,
                    "lmsets": "highways;allow_all"
                  }
                }
              },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `preference` option and it can be set to `shortest`.